# Translate XML Schema pattern to Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex, expression

Who can help me to translate this XML Schema pattern "[0-9]+-([0-9]|K)" to java regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pattern with a snippet on how to use it.

\\ is there to escape the \ in a string. \d represents [0-9]. I do not recall if the - has to be escaped so I did it just in case.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\-[\\d|K]"); //The string is the pattern
Matcher m = p.matcher(whatYouWantToMatch);
boolean b = m.matches();
```

Comment: Thanks! I just find out that it is compatible... this worked fine: s.matches("[0-9]+-([0-9]|K)")

Comment: now you got it ;) I used with your regex: s.matches("\\d+\\-[\\d|K]")

Comment: Regular expressions in XSD are implicitly anchored at start and end by ^ and $, but regular expressions in Java are not, so add them explicitly, so this anwser is incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536762/java-regex-vs-xsd-regex

Answer (score 0):

At least this case is compatible with java regex...

```
String s = "test cases here";
s.matches("[0-9]+-([0-9]|K)") //works OK.
```