# Java regex vs XSD regex

Tags: java, regex, xsd

I have an XSD with a field that has the following pattern value:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1,6}(/([IXCDVML]+)|([0-9]+))?"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

How can I write the above XSD in Java?

Comment: The same thing should work with `String.matches()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions in XSD are implicitly anchored at start and end by `^` and `$`, but regular expressions in Java are not, so add them explicitly:

```
^[0-9]{1,6}(/([IXCDVML]+)|([0-9]+))?$
```

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs):

> **Note**:  Unlike some popular regular expression languages (including
>   those defined by Perl and standard Unix utilities), the regular
>   expression language defined here implicitly anchors all regular
>   expressions at the head and tail, as the most common use of regular
>   expressions in ·pattern· is to match entire literals.